# osCommerce: Recurring payments

Tags: payment, oscommerce, recurring-billing

I have searched a lot the web, trying to get some module for recurring payments but not succeeded. Can anyone know how to integrate or implement Recurring payments to osCommerce products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use paypal, you can use the [Paypal Recurring Billing Module](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/6917) (config your account for recurring payments in https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring )

Comment: This is right, but this one is for previous version...

Comment: For Oscommerce 3.0.x there's no paypal payment module. You can make one if you need (you can take another payment module and modify it for paypal. And publish it on the addons page!!). But... You must no use Oscommerce 3.0.x in a real store: `This release is recommended for developers and users who are participating in its development and are providing feedback. Other users should wait until v3.1.0 for a feature complete and production ready release.`

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, i modified this module and now working right for my need.

Comment: happy to be useful `:D` (don't forget to publish the module in the addons repository http://addons.oscommerce.com :P)

Comment: Hello ime. Can you please explain to me how you managed to do the paypal recurring payments for oscommerce.. I am reading through thge paypal developers documentation but i am a little bit lost..if you can upload your solution to addons.oscommerce.com or github i would really appreciate it